Riverpod annotation for State Provider
I am new to Riverpod. I am using Riverpod Annotation to generate providers.
As for Future Provider, I did it like this.
@riverpod
Future<void> login(LoginRef ref) async {
  final login = sl<LoginUsecase>();
  final saveAuth = sl<SaveAuthUsecase>();

  final loginForm = ref.read(loginFormProvider);
  final input = LoginUsecaseInput(
    password: loginForm.password!,
    email: loginForm.email!,
  );

  final output = await login(input);

  final saveAuthInput = SaveAuthUsecaseInput(bearerToken: output.bearerToken);

  await saveAuth(saveAuthInput);
}

This is my State Provider
final authStepProvider = StateProvider<AuthStep>((ref) => AuthStep.register); 
How to do it with annotations?
I tried:
@riverpod
class AuthStep extends _$AuthStep {
  @override
  AuthStepModel build() {
    return AuthStepModel.register;
  }
}

But when I try to update its state like this:
ref.read(authStepProvider.notifier).state = AuthStepModel.login; 
It gives a warning:
The member 'state' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:riverpod/src/notifier.dart'.
Also, this is for StateNotifier Provider & what I need is StateProvider

Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

just add method to mutate state:
@riverpod
class AuthStep extends _$AuthStep {
  @override
  AuthStepModel build() {
    return AuthStepModel.register;
  }
  
  void onLogIn() {
    state = AuthStepModel.login;
  }
}

and call it like this:
ref.read(authStepProvider.notifier).onLogIn();


I have found the solution in Riverpod official documentation.
https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_state_notifier
Migrating StateProvider to Notifier.
@riverpod
class AuthStep extends _$AuthStep {
  @override
  AuthStepModel build() => AuthStepModel.register;

  @override
  set state(AuthStepModel newState) => super.state = newState;

  AuthStepModel update(AuthStepModel Function(AuthStepModel state) cb) =>
      state = cb(state);
}

